Checking for self-intersection in Shapely MultiPolygon
I have a MultiPolygon in Shapely which potentially might have millions of Polygons. I need to find out if such a MultiPolygon has any self-intersection - I don't need to find the intersection itself, just check whether there is one. Is there any efficient way to do so - preferrably in Python?
As far as I can see, the usual intersection methods all depend on other polys/multipolys/etc. Iterating over the polygons seems unpractical due to the size of the MultiPolygon being arbitrary, often in the millions.

I would try https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.is_valid_reason.html and find the response "'Ring Self-intersection..."

Millions of parts to a multipolygon seems... excessive. I suggest you review your methodology to find a better way to represent this data.

Possibly the typical is_valid or is_simple aren't optimized for this situation... If this is te case, probably converting the multipolygon to a list of polygons with shapely.get_parts and then using STRTree.query to check for intersections in an efficient way will do the trick...

Just a guess, but polygonizing a raster can make complex multipolygons.
